# If $A\sim B$, then $r(A)=r(B)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Theorem: If $A\sim B$, then $r(A)=r(B)$, where $r(A)$ denotes the rank of $A$.

I would appreciate any corrections on the proofs below and any alternates. Many thanks for your time. I have 2 proofs:

Proof 1: uses the definition that $A\sim B$ if they represent the same linear map.
Proof 2: uses the definition that $A\sim B$ if $B=PAP^{-1}$.
Proof 1
Step 1. If $A\sim B$ then by definition $A$ and $B$ represent the same linear map, $T:V→W$
2. By the theorem that every vector space of dimension $n$ over $F$ is isomorphic to $F^n$, $T:V→W$ can be represented by $T:F^n→F^m$
3. By the theorem that any linear map $T:F^n→F^m$ is of the form $T(v)=Av$ for some matrix $A_{m\times n}$, $T(v)=Av$ and $T(v)=Bv$ as $A$ and $B$ represent the same $T$
4. By the theorem if $A_{m\times n}$ is a matrix over $F$, $T:F^n→F^m$ is a linear map and $T(v)=Av$ then $r(T)=r(A)$, $r(T)=r(A)$ and $r(T)=r(B)$ as $A$ and $B$ represent the same $T$. Therefore $r(A)=r(B)$
Q.E.D.

Proof 2
Step 1. By the definition of similar matrices, $B=PAP^{-1}$, therefore $r(B)=r(PAP^{-1})$
2. By the theorem $r(B)\ge r(AB)$, $r(A)\ge r(PAP^{-1})$ therefore $r(A)\ge r(B)$
3. Also as $B=PAP^{-1}$, $P^{-1}B=P^{-1}PAP^{-1}$, $P^{-1}BP=P^{-1}PAP^{-1}P=IAI=A$, therefore $A=P^{-1}BP$ and by $r(B)\ge r(AB)$, $r(B)\ge r(P^{-1}BP)$ therefore $r(B)\ge r(A)$
4. As $r(A)\ge r(B)$ and $r(B)\ge r(A)$, $r(A)=r(B)$ 
Q.E.D.

Comment: You should also say what $r(A)$ is. I suppose it is $rank(A)$?

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first proof is fine, except for the fact that steps 2 and 3 are irrelevant to the proof.

Your second proof is also fine.  I would make step 2 of this proof more explicit by writing
$$
r(A) \geq r(PA) \geq r(PAP^{-1}).
$$
Step 3 can be abbreviated into "by symmetry, we must also have $r(B) \geq r(A)$".  The point here is that in the first two steps, we showed that "$A$ is similar to $B$" implies that $r(A) \geq r(B)$.  However, "$A$ is similar to $B$" means that "$B$ is similar to $A$", which means that applying the same logic tells us that $r(B) \geq r(A)$.  We are implicitly using the fact that similarity is an equivalence relation, though.

Comment: I like your thinking on step 3, thanks.